# A confusion about the proof of "Every Cauchy sequence converges"

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

In the book of *Writing Proofs in Analysis* by J.M Kane, at page 78, it is given that

[image]

However, in the case 2, he states that since $p$ is an accumulation point of $A$, there exists $k> N$, but the fact that $p$ is an accumulation point only says that $(B(p,\epsilon)- \{ p\}) \cap A \not = \emptyset$, hence there exits $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $x_{n_1} \in B(p,\epsilon)$, so how can the author conclude from that $n_1 > N$ ?

Comment: Since there are **infinite** values of A within $\;\epsilon/2\;$ of $\;p\;$ , then you can find an index $\;k>N\;$ s.t. ...etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio How do you know that there are infinite vales of $A$ within $\epsilon /2$ ? Can we derive it from its definition ?

Comment: Of course: if A is infinite (in a metric space), then the very definition of accumulation point leads us to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a quantifier: the fact that $p$ is an accumulation point says that for *every* positive radius $r$ the intersection $(B(p,r)- \{ p\}) \cap A$ is nonempty. This in turn implies that the intersection is infinite, for all radii. (Why? Consider what happens for $r=1/n$. We shrink the ball each time we increment $n$, yet still the intersection is nonempty!)

Choosing the radius to be $\epsilon/2$, we see there are *infinitely many* $a_n$ within $\epsilon/2$ of $p$. Hence there must be a $k>N$ such that $a_k$ is within $\epsilon/2$ of $p$.